# Why is the Acrobat giving me the error?

Tags: animations

The Acrobat loads my PDF animation file and it shows me the animation with wrong background and a second page under it with the message:
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Temporary page!
LATEX was unable to guess the total number of pages correctly. As was some unprocessed data that should have been added to the this extra page has been added to receive it.
If you rerun the document (without altering it) this surplus page away, because LATEX now knows how many pages to expect for this
document.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
I make a GIF animation file with Maple that has no problems whatsoever. Then I convert this GIF file to a bunch of .png frame files. Then I use LualaTex with "\animategraphics[controls,loop,width=7in]{6}{FROM_EZGIFM-}{1}{200}." Everything works just fine, but the Acrobat does not give me the presentation right. The controls work OK and the images look just great on it!
Please help.

Comment: the additional page normally means that you should run lualatex a second time. The rest of your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike. I understand now.